# Paypal payflow order summary blank

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to add an order summary to paypal payflow pro, here's my code:

```
$summary = "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale".
           "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=TestItem".
           "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=1234567890".
           "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=ItemDescription".
           "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=2.10".
           "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1".
           "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=2.10";

$post_data = "USER=" . $PF_USER
            .   "&VENDOR=" . $PF_VENDOR
            .   "&PARTNER=" . $PF_PARTNER
            .   "&PWD=" . $PF_PWD
            .   "&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y"
            .   "&SECURETOKENID=" . $secureTokenID
            .   "&TRXTYPE=S"
            .    $summary
            .   "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=2.10"
            .   "&AMT=2.10";
```

And the result I get is... [image]

I've been searching for a solution for hours... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to display the order details other than total amount , tax and the shipping amount on the hosted checkout pages when using the Layout "A" or "B". You can use the Layout "C" which is an iframe and you can display the order information around the iframe using your custom integration .

Comment: Is this still the same in 2016?